# two button to open two new activity

Tags: android, button, android-intent

I am learning Android, I created two buttons in main activity and then from each button I want to open new activity, button 2 is working but button 1 doesn't works, my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn;
    Button btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Allactivities.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Review.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Xml code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btnbluee"
    android:text="@string/button_tittle"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="192dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btnorange"
    android:text="@string/button_title"
    android:onClick="onClick" />
```

Comment: You didn't set a listener to btn2. You are assigning button1 to btn2 ...

Comment: @MichaelB. I have tried but I got error(Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> button 2 is working but button one is not work,

this is because you need to add a listener to each button:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Allactivities.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Review.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

and

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Allactivities.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Review.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

and just a suggestion..

try to be consistent between layout and code, you will spare pains in the neck...

```
 btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
 btn2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

must be:

```
 btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 btn2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Answer (score 0):

just do like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn;
    Button btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Review.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Allactivities.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
//set listener button 2 (btn)
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Allactivities.class) ;
        startActivity(intent) ;
    }
});

//set listener button 1 (btn2)
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Review.class) ;
        startActivity(i) ;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is ok, but you can improve the solution using this example:

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btn;
    Button btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent  = null;
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1: {
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Allactivities.class);
            }break;
            case R.id.button2: {
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Review.class);
            }break;
        }
        if(intent != null){
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `onClick` you can handle the buttons actions asking for theirs id and you will write less code. I only post my solution to improve or give another option.